# Business Objects Web Intelligence-style reporting in a Winform app. Is this possible?

Tags: winforms, business-objects

I have a WinForm app that displays results in a Gridview control. If a user right mouse clicks on a row, he can then, from a popup menu, select a command to perform on the row much like windows File Explorer.

But now I want to be able to give the user the ability to construct a filter so that he can control which rows are displayed in the grid w/o effecting the functionality of the application. I would also like the user to be able to select the columns/fields that he sees in the grid.

For the basis of this question, let's assume that the data displayed in grid comes from a single table.

business Objects' Web Intelligence and Desktop Intelligence applications give me very flexible and powerful reporting capabilities, but I want to integrate this capability into my WinForm application.

Does Business Objects, or maybe Crystal Reports provide this sort of functionality? I can construct my own query builder but I'd rather not reinvent sliced bread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like developerexpres [xtragrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Grid/).
Its has filtering, column customizing etc.

If you want pivottables/olap like tables they have [XtraPivotgrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Pivot_Grid/)
Usually the filtering is clientside but they have the possibilitie to generate serverside queries..